# Parsing XML with Namespaces C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I have been working on parsing this XML data all day. It seems like my problem is namespaces. I thought a had a glimmer of hope with my last website http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30965/Read-XML-with-Namespace-resolution-using-XLinq-XEl but it failed as well. Each time I run the code below I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." There seems to be many ways of parsing XML with C# but these namespaces are killing me. What am I doing wrong?

Do keep in mind I am new to XML and C# and use to parsing JSON data. And yes I have Googled several way to parse XML data and nothing has be useful in this case. I can get XML without the namespaces to work but with them always has that error.

C# Code:

```
 XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);

 XNamespace ns2 = "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd";
 string val = element.Element(ns2 + "ItemDimensions").Element(ns2 + "Heigth").Value;
                                Console.WriteLine(val);
```

XML Data:

```
<ns2:ItemAttributes xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
  <ns2:Author>Troelsen, Andrew</ns2:Author>
  <ns2:Binding>Paperback</ns2:Binding>
  <ns2:Brand>Apress</ns2:Brand>
  <ns2:Edition>5</ns2:Edition>
  <ns2:ItemDimensions>
    <ns2:Height Units="inches">9.21</ns2:Height>
    <ns2:Length Units="inches">7.48</ns2:Length>
    <ns2:Width Units="inches">2.52</ns2:Width>
    <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">5.80</ns2:Weight>
  </ns2:ItemDimensions>
  <ns2:IsAutographed>false</ns2:IsAutographed>
  <ns2:IsEligibleForTradeIn>true</ns2:IsEligibleForTradeIn>
  <ns2:IsMemorabilia>false</ns2:IsMemorabilia>
  <ns2:Label>Apress</ns2:Label>
  <ns2:Languages>
    <ns2:Language>
      <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
      <ns2:Type>Unknown</ns2:Type>
    </ns2:Language>
    <ns2:Language>
      <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
      <ns2:Type>Original Language</ns2:Type>
    </ns2:Language>
    <ns2:Language>
      <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
      <ns2:Type>Published</ns2:Type>
    </ns2:Language>
  </ns2:Languages>
  <ns2:ListPrice>
    <ns2:Amount>59.99</ns2:Amount>
    <ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode>
  </ns2:ListPrice>
  <ns2:Manufacturer>Apress</ns2:Manufacturer>
  <ns2:NumberOfItems>1</ns2:NumberOfItems>
  <ns2:NumberOfPages>1752</ns2:NumberOfPages>
  <ns2:PackageDimensions>
    <ns2:Height Units="inches">2.60</ns2:Height>
    <ns2:Length Units="inches">9.20</ns2:Length>
    <ns2:Width Units="inches">7.50</ns2:Width>
    <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">5.80</ns2:Weight>
  </ns2:PackageDimensions>
  <ns2:PartNumber>9781430225492</ns2:PartNumber>
  <ns2:ProductGroup>Book</ns2:ProductGroup>
  <ns2:ProductTypeName>ABIS_BOOK</ns2:ProductTypeName>
  <ns2:PublicationDate>2010-05-14</ns2:PublicationDate>
  <ns2:Publisher>Apress</ns2:Publisher>
  <ns2:SmallImage>
    <ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51h9Sju5NKL._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL>
    <ns2:Height Units="pixels">75</ns2:Height>
    <ns2:Width Units="pixels">61</ns2:Width>
  </ns2:SmallImage>
  <ns2:Studio>Apress</ns2:Studio>
  <ns2:Title>Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform</ns2:Title>
</ns2:ItemAttributes>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: element name is `Height` and not `Heigth`.

You can use this code to get `Height` value:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);

XNamespace ns2 = "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd";


string val = doc.Document.Descendants(ns2 + "ItemDimensions")
    .FirstOrDefault().Element(ns2 + "Height").Value;

Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Comment: Thank you this help out a lot. Actually I can't believe I spelled Height wrong. It's been a long day and I am on last burst of energy.