# Check if element exists in XML using c#

Tags: c#, xml

Why do I get false value for hasIdentifier variable, when I see in i-th document anything_start_i.xml that there is `<identifier>value</identifier>` element.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(args[0] + "/?verb=GetRecord&metadataPrefix=p3dm&identifier=" + i);
doc.Save("anything_start" + i + ".xml");
bool hasIdentifier = doc.Elements("identifier").Any();
Console.WriteLine(hasIdentifier);
```

Tried with Descendants instead of Elements, and again false.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <OAI-PMH xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
      <responseDate>...</responseDate>
      <request verb="GetRecord" identifier="1"</request>
      <GetRecord>
        <record>
          <header>
            <identifier>1</identifier>
            <datestamp>...</datestamp>
          </header>
          <metadata>
            <P3DM xmlns="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
              <MODELINFOID>1</MODELINFOID>
              <TITLE>Roth</TITLE>
  ....
```

Well, I would like to save all documents, and trying to stop saving when there is no documents any more (actually there is but without meaningful data). So, this is how i started:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var i = 1;
  bool work = true;
  do{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(args[0] + "/?verb=GetRecord&metadataPrefix=p3dm&identifier=" + i);
    bool hasIdentifier = doc.Elements("identifier").Any();
    if (hasIdentifier) {
        doc.Save("anything" + i + ".xml");
        i++;
     }else{ 
        work = false;
     }
  } while (work);
```

Comment: Please add sample input/output. If your XML is big, include only relevant parts.

Comment: Please show sample XML (valid but small, 5-7 lines). Likely duplicate one of many "why `x:` breaks my searches in XML" AKA "how to use namespaces to select nodes".

Comment: Indeed there is default namespace. There are couple questions about it already - i.e. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040926/parsing-xml-with-namespaces-c-sharp. (Should be duplicate, but no vote left).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XNamespace ns = "you namespace goes here";
bool hasIdentifier = doc.Descendants(ns + "identifier").Any();
```